# MS明朝やメイリオ フォントを Linux 上で PDF への埋め込み目的で使用することはライセンスで許可されていますか？

Tags: ライセンス, font

MS明朝、MSゴシック、メイリオフォントをLinuxサーバにインストールして使う場合、ライセンス違反になるでしょうか？

PDFに文字を埋め込むためにこれらのフォントを使いたいと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

**後から見つけた以下内容によって記述順番を変更**
(コメントされた時点とは内容がズレていますので注意)

---

WindowsのPC/Serverなどからコピーしたり変換するのではなく、正式にそのフォントのライセンスを購入すれば利用することが出来るようです。
こちらの記事で解説していますね。
[Microsoft 製品付属のフォントのライセンス](https://hebikuzure.wordpress.com/2018/01/19/microsoft-font-lisence/)

> Microsoft のテクニカル フォーラム（マイクロソフト コミュニティや TechNet フォーラム）で時々出てくる話題なのでメモ。

> Windows や Office の製品に付属しているフォントは、それぞれの製品のライセンス条項（EULA）にフォントに関するセクションがあるのでそれに従うが、一般的には再配布、複製、編集はできない、とされています。

> フォント ライセンスの購入
> 上記の引用でも触れられていますが、Microsoft が著作権を保有しているフォントの多くは[Monotype Imaging](http://www.monotype.com/jp/)で取り扱っており、ライセンスを購入して利用することができます。実際の購入はオンライン ストア[fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/ja)から行えます。

例えばこんなライセンスが使えるのではないでしょうか？
[よくあるご質問 よくあるご質問一覧 Fonts.comのショッピング ライセンスの種類](https://monotype.support/faq/fontscom-shopping/font-licenses/497)

> サーバーライセンス
> サーバーにフォントをインストールして、書体をご利用いただける年間ライセンス。
> 実装するフォント数、サーバ台数およびCPU数により費用が異なります。
> 電子帳票やクラウドソリューションなど、サーバー側でドキュメント生成やデザイン出力などを行う場合の年間ライセンスです。パートナー様経由でのご契約も可能です。

つまり **代替フォントとして使えそうなフォントまたはおすすめフォントをご存知ないでしょうか？** に関しては上記サイトからライセンス購入すれば希望する内容が実現出来そうなので、詳細はそこに問い合わせてみてはどうでしょう？

---

**当初以下の内容を中心に書いていましたが質問の意図とはズレていたので参考程度に**

質問に明確には書かれていませんが、手段としてWindowsのPC/Serverなどからファイルを抜き出したりフォーマット変換してLinuxサーバーにコピーするような方法を取った場合はライセンス違反になるでしょう。

こちらの記事に、出来ないとかそうした権利はない、と書かれています。

[Redistribution and extended rights - Font redistribution FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions) for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq#redistribution-and-extended-rights)

> Apart from the document embedding rights described previously, you may not redistribute the Windows fonts. You may not copy them to other computers or servers, and you may not convert them to other formats, including bitmap formats, or modify them.

> 前述のドキュメント埋め込み権とは別に、Windowsフォントを再配布することはできません。それらを他のコンピューターやサーバーにコピーしたり、ビットマップ形式を含む他の形式に変換したり、変更したりすることはできません。

[Web - Font redistribution FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions) for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq#web)

> Web fonts are fonts that are hosted on a web server. You do not have rights to:
>
> - copy fonts from a Windows installation to a web server, a process known as web font “self-hosting”.
> - convert the font to the formats typically associated with web fonts, such as the WOFF or WOFF2 format.

> 次の権利はありません。
>
> - インストールされたWindowsからWebサーバーヘフォントをコピーする。Webフォントの"自己ホスティング"と呼ばれる処理です。
> - フォントを、WOFFやWOFF2形式など、Webフォントに通常関連付けられている形式に変換します。

---

`Web`の章ではなく`Document embedding`の方が適切では？とのコメントで、PDFに埋め込むなら条件が変わるのでは？ということだと思われますが、そのページの頭から2つ目の文章に、以下のように書かれています。

> A Windows application can use the fonts to render content to a screen, allow that content to be edited, and allow that content to be output to a device, like a printer. Here are answers to common questions about using these fonts.

> Windowsアプリケーションは、フォントを使用してコンテンツを画面にレンダリングし、そのコンテンツを編集して、そのコンテンツをプリンターなどのデバイスに出力できるようにすることができます。これらのフォントの使用に関する一般的な質問への回答は次のとおりです。

つまり`Windows上で動作するWindowsアプリケーションがフォントを使ったり編集する`なら可能である、と考えられます。

Comment: 質問に対する回答としては、参照しているページで "Document embedding" の段落の方がより適切な気がします。

Comment: その処理を行うのがWindowsのPCやサーバーならばそうかもしれませんが、Linux上で行うなら違うのでは？

Comment: Linux サーバとは書かれていますが、PDF (=ドキュメント) への埋め込みが目的であり、 web フォントとしての利用を想定しているとは書かれていないです。

Answer (score 0):

kunifさんも参照されていますが、[Font redistribution FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions) for Windows - Document embedding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq#document-embedding)での記述が答えになるでしょう。

> **When can I use document embedding?**
>
> The brief answer: If an application follows the rules and restrictions defined in the OpenType or TrueType specification, you can use it to embed Windows supplied fonts in any document file it creates.

つまりOpenTypeやTrueTypeにはフォントのプロパティとして埋め込み可否の情報が含まれており、各フォントの設定に従うとのことです。

手元の環境でいくつか例を挙げるとこうなっていました。

- Font embeddability: Editable

  - ＭＳ明朝
  - メイリオ
  - 游明朝
  - HG明朝（Office付属）
- Font embeddability: Preview/Print

  - BIZ UD明朝

Preview/Printなフォントは編集可能なPDFには認められないということになるかと。

また、まっとうなPDF作成ソフトであればフォント埋め込み時にこのライセンスフラグを参照するでしょうから、「埋め込み不可エラー」が発生しない限り、使用可能かと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

質問に追記するつもりだったと思われる項目について
**「代替フォントとして使えそうなフォント」**

---

質問者さんのいう「MS明朝やメイリオ」の代替, とは何なのかが具体的でない

1. フォントの見た目, 書体・デザインが似ていること
2. そのプラットフォームに於いて標準的に使えそうなフォント
3. あるいはその他の意味

---

①に関して, ほぼ同じデザインのフォントを使いたいということなら デザインの似ているようなフリーフォント探すのが楽かもだけど, それはほとんど盗用になりかねないので止めたほうがよいでしょう。(あるいは他の回答にもあるように購入という形がよい)。
その辺りをここに詳しく記すのはムリなので検索でヒットしたのを載せておきます https://chizai-faq.com/2__copyright/361

---

②に関しては, 例えば Ubuntuであれば リポジトリーに用意されていて 他のディストリビューションも大抵揃ってるはず

```bash
# Ubuntu あるいは Debianでも同様に可能
$ apt list font* | wc
    527    1684   27588
```

500種類ほどのうち, ほとんどは日本語フォントではないが 日本語フォントも含まれている

- [IPAフォント](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)

  - 派生フォント [Takaoフォント](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88#Takao%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)
- [Noto](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto)
  … ノー"豆腐" からの名称。`Noto Sans CJK` / `Noto Serif CJK` など

個人的には Noto使ってれば(標準的に使う目的であれば)問題ないと思うけど
オススメフォントの話になると好みの問題なので stackoverflowの質問としてだんだん適さない方向になってきます

Comment: PDF資料生成時のフォントとしては Notoはそれなり一般的ではあるけれど, (個人的には ＆) 場合によっては プログラミング用フォント使うかも (PlemolJP など)

Answer (score -1):

windows11のWSLでubuntuの環境を作って(日本語環境にする必要があります)
/usr/share/fonts/のフォルダにフォントをインストールすればLibreOfficeで使えました。

Comment: 技術的な実現方法に関する質問ではなく、ライセンス上、使用許諾されている範囲について尋ねられています。